# How can I connect external peer to existing Hyperledger fabric (running on Kubernetes)?

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running my Hyperledger Fabric on Gcloud Kubernetes cluster. Now I want to extend the network by connecting external peers (running of different hosts). Help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you need to join nodes to your cluster or reference them as external service from K8S? in this last case take a look at ExternalName service: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Comment: Can you clarify the question please?

Comment: I am running Hyperledger cluster on a Gcloud kubernetes and I want to connect my laptop to the chain.

Comment: Hi @akshayhundia did you find a solution?